# Vue using v-for to render computed properties after loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using `v-for` to iterate over a `computed` property, and that computed property depends on a `data` attribute, which is initiated as `null`. I will load it in beforeMount.

here is the pseudo-code:

```
<th v-for="item in computed_list">
{{ item.name }}
</th>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'test',
  data () {
    return {
      whole_list: null
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.load()
  },

  computed: {
    computed_list: function() {
      if (!this.series) return []
      return this.whole_list.slice(1,3)
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async load () {
      let res = await some_api_call()
      this.whole_list = res['data']
    }
  }


}
</script>
```

But somehow it failed to render the list, and report `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`.

I'm new to Vue and not very familiar with its lifecycle. The basic idea is to render list of data, but those data are loaded somehow after the Vue instance is created. Not sure if it's the correct way to do this.

Comment: initialize `whole_list` as an empty array instead

Answer (score 2):

Initializing a data item to null breaks the VueJS state watching functionality so it won't know about changes to it. Initialize it as an empty object or array instead.

https://012.vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html

> The reason for this is that Vue observes data changes by recursively walking the data object and converting existing properties into reactive getters and setters using Object.defineProperty. If a property is not present when the instance is created, Vue will not be able to track it.
>
> You don’t have to set every single nested property in your data though. It is ok to initialize a field as an empty object, and set it to a new object with nested structures later, because Vue will be able to walk the nested properties of this new object and observe them.

Comment: Initializing a data property with the value `null` will work.

Comment: I've always had it do strange things like in this question when set to null. Especially with arrays

Comment: If you come across one of these strange things I'd be curious. I have not had any problems with initializing values with `null` , yet.